# Fetch cookie in variable (valid for 24hrs) and send to mysql

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, cookies

I need a variable which is valid for one day. The variable should identify the website user and should be unique for that user. Once I have this variable I want to store it in a mysql column. (Here I know what to do ... but I'm struggling to create such a variable)

I further have a validation check if that record already exist in the table or not. So for 24hrs I can't create a new record.

I'm not sure how to achieve this ... I guess via a cookie which is valid for one day? (sorry I'm fairly new to cookies). I'm already struggling to alert the cookie (see below):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }   

// Inline Button in Table

var cookie_variable = $('#table').on('click', 'a.cookie_button', function () {

    alert(document.cookie);

} );

});
```

Alert Result:

[object Object]=[object Object]; cookieconsent_dismissed=yes

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what exactly you want to do/are having trouble with, but I've made changes to your code that will make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.setCookie = function(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date() + (exdays||1)*24*60*60*1000;
        // defaulted to 1 day - by using "exdays OR 1" - if exdays not specified
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    window.getCookie = function(cname) {
        match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(cname + '=([^;]+)'));
        // above is a regular expression, used to find the cookie value
        return (match ? match[1]: match); // returns cookie value or null
    }   

    // Inline Button in Table

    $("#table").click(function(e){
        alert(document.cookie);
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks dev. but now I only see 'cookieconsent_dismissed=yes' in my pop up window. At the end I need a variable which is unique to the website visitor ... attach a date to it ... fetch it and send it to mysql ... but I already don't understand why I can't see anything in the popup

Comment: E.g. wenn I do this: var cookieList = (document.cookie) ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [];       .... and alert it I get:     PHPSESSID= //and some code .... why do I only see the session ID?